# Variable not available outside function

Tags: bash, pipe, variable, function

I'm having difficulties understanding the following example I created.

The variable glob_var gets changed inside the test() function, but the original value remains outside of the function:

```
test() {
  read var
  glob_var=$var
  echo '$glob_var in test(): '$glob_var 
}


glob_var='org'
echo '$glob_var start: '$glob_var
echo new | test
echo '$glob_var end: '$glob_var
```

**Output**

```
$glob_var start: org
$glob_var in test(): new
$glob_var end: org
```

I'm suspecting that the pipe starts a new process. If that's the case, what would be an alternative way to retrieve values from the test function?